# See references marked with a number in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

My references section is not referencing it with a number (maybe it's because of the template configuration, I am a rookie using LaTeX). How could I change it to see it, for instance, like this:

```
[1] Carrero, J., Rodríguez, I., and Rubio, F. (2022b). A tool...

[2] Chainlink (2022). Chainlink project. https://chain.link...
```

This is the link of a basic project using the template: https://www.overleaf.com/5365237922rthmwmrgckgx

[image]

Comment: Please include a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), we do not even know which bibliography package you are using so the question is likely impossible to answer as-is

Comment: @JamesT Thank you so much and sry, I've just added the link. It seems that I didn't write the `year` in `@misc` tag, so I solved that problem but I got another one: see the references with a number (I updated the question already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template file to which you provided a link features the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` toward the vey end of the file. Now, the `apalike` bibliography style can only produce authoryear-style citation callouts. It *cannot* produce numeric-style citation call-outs.

To obtain numeric-style citation call-outs, I suggest you

- delete the existing .aux and .bbl files,
- change `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`, and
- change the instruction (contained on line 37 of the template file) `\usepackage[round, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}` to `\usepackage[numbers, square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}`.

Then, run a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more, to recreate the formatted bibliography and all citation call-outs, which will now be in numeric style.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you so much. Just a question: what files are .aux and .bbl files? I can´t find that extension in the project files

Comment: Last question: the bibliography is sorted by alphabet, is there a simple way to sort it in order of appearance?

Comment: @Joncarre - To sort the formatted bibliographic entries by order of the first appearance of the associated `\cite` commands, change `abbrvnat` to `unsrtnat`. If `main.tex` is the name of the main tex file, then `main.aux` and `main.bbl` are auxilliary files produced by running LaTeX and BibTeX on main.